# get eigenvalues only using sapply in R

Tags: r

I've tried many different things to get the eigenvalues only when looping through the list but did'nt work. That's the code:

```
myarray=matrix(rexp(200),50,5)
list.of.matrices <- apply(expand.grid(rep(list(c(FALSE, TRUE)), ncol(myarray))),
                              1, function(j)myarray[, j, drop = FALSE])
list.of.cov.matrices=sapply(list.of.matrices, cov)
eigen.val<- sapply(list.of.cov.matrices, eigen$values)
```

Also tried:

```
eigen.val=apply(list.of.cov.matrices, 1, function(eigen) FUN(eigen, only.values = T))
```

Finally I would like to construct a table with the eigenvalues for each matrix.

To build the table I use:

```
eigen.sum=data.frame(
  list.eigen.of.cor.matrices=rep(1:length( eigen.val), sapply( eigen.val, length)),
  y=unlist( eigen.val)
```

This does the table but then additional manipulation in excel must follow so would like to do it straight forward if possible.

Comment: Regarding table construction, how do you want to do it in R? Your matrices are of different dimensions, which means your eigen vectors will be of different lengths.

Comment: since `eigen` is the name of a function, you should really avoid using the same name for your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, you have a `0*0` matrix in your input, for which it returns an error. Second, the way you call the `eigen` function (in the first command) is not correct.

Basically, you'll have to check if the dimension of matrix is NOT `0*0` and then call the `eigen` function correctly. Try this:

```
eigen <- sapply(list.of.cov.matrices, function(x) {
    if (prod(dim(x)) > 0) {
        eigen(x)$values
    }
})
```